# simple image data passing from collection view to view controller fail

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uicollectionview, optional-values

This is seriously starting to drive me crazy, since it s really simple.
I have a collectionviewcell that gets images from phone library

When i tap a cell, i get the index of the fetched collection (i m using Photo Framework), then send the selected image (through PHImageManage's imageFromAsset) to a new view controller, assign this image to a new UIimage property and then try to display it on my UIimageView outlet
FAIL !
In the debug Window, I can see that the image is passing from the collectionviewcontroller to my FullImageViewController, and I dont understand why I get an error on my outlet (returns NIL for ever)

here s a bit of code, and a bug capture -- The collectioncontroller first

```
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell: PhotoCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier(identifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as! PhotoCollectionViewCell

 //   cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    let asset: PHAsset = photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: cellSize, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil) { (reuslt:UIImage?, info:[NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in
        if let image = reuslt {
            cell.displaythunmb(image)
        }
    }

    return cell

}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let asset=photosAsset[indexPath.item] as! PHAsset
    let size:CGSize = CGSizeMake(200, 200)

    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .AspectFit, options: nil) { (result:UIImage?, info:[NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Void in
        let controller:FullImageViewController = FullImageViewController()
        if let image = result {
        controller.dislpayFullImage(image)
    }
    }

    performSegueWithIdentifier("gofull", sender: self)

}
```

and here's the fullImageViewController

```
class FullImageViewController: UIViewController {
var image:UIImage = UIImage()

@IBOutlet weak var fullimage: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    navigationController?.hidesBarsOnTap = true

}
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    //dislpayFullImage()

}

func dislpayFullImage(fullimg:UIImage){

    if let monimage:UIImage? = fullimg {
        image=monimage!
         fullimage.image = image
    }

}
```

}

this gives me "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the "fullimage.image = image" line

I've tried to unwrap, force unwrap and so on, nothing seems to work

In the debt window, when I follow the properties I have to following :

fullimg UIImage 0x00007ff3fb6506f0  0x00007ff3fb6506f0
self    test.FullImageViewController    0x00007ff3fb6526e0  0x00007ff3fb6526e0
UIKit.UIViewController  UIViewController
image   UIImage 0x00007ff3fb6506f0  0x00007ff3fb6506f0

fullimage   UIImageView!    nil None

monimage    UIImage?    0x00007ff3fb6506f0  0x00007ff3fb6506f0

Any idea where I m messing up >

Comment: Using `if let monimage: UIImage?` kind of defeats the purpose of using `if let`. You only want it to continue if `fullimg` has a value but now it will still continue even if it's `nil`

Comment: It seems like your `fullimage` property is nil. How are you initializing it?

Comment: My guess would be, you're assigning an image to `fullimage` before the view is even loaded, therefor `fullimage` is still `nil`.

Comment: you are right, sorry for that, though it does not work either with `if let monimage: UIImage` still crashes

Comment: The first comment was just telling you you're using `if let` incorrectly. The second comment is most probably the cause of the crash ;)

Comment: @MarcKhadpe simply through the outlet .. (If I understood your question)

Comment: @Eendje mmm, so Instead of calling a function I should just pass the property and update the viewWillappear func ?

Comment: @YannMassard Your view controller is being created programmatically though, with a call to `FullImageViewController()`, rather than being loaded from a storyboard. So outlets normally wouldn't be set automatically. Are you overriding `init()` to load the view from a nib file?

Comment: @MarcKhadpe you are right, mmm could you elaborate on how to init it ? I thought that referencing view controllers would include outlets

Comment: @YannMassard Normally, you would want to set up a segue in the storyboard and then implement `prepareForSegue()` in your view controller to do your setup. See Eendje's answer for an example of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an instance of `FullImageViewController` programmatically but you are using an `IBOutlet` in this view controller.

You probably want to instantiate it using storyboard, so you'll have to do something like this:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let destination = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("yourIdentifier") as! FullImageViewController
```

Don't forget to set the identifier for your `FullImageViewController` though.

EDIT: Since you're using a segue, you should handle passing the data in `prepareForSegue(_:)`:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "gofull" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! FullImageViewController
        destination.someImage = result
    }
}
```

But accessing `fullimage` before the view is loaded will still cause a crash, so you should try passing the value to `fullimage` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

In your `FullImageViewController`:

```
var someImage: UIImage?

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    if let image = someImage { fullimage.image = image }
}
```

Comment: Tsk for the help :) now the fullimaage.image property is correctly updated, and no more crashes, but still no image on screen. Should I also instantiate my viewcontroller as you suggested earlier ?

Comment: No, there is already an instance of that view controller. You don't want to create a new instance. Not seeing the image is another problem though. Is the outlet connected properly etc?